# Firebase: What is being done behind the onDisconnect method? (AS3)

Tags: actionscript-3, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

First, I want to mention, I understand how the Firebase `onDisconnect` method works in JavaScript. It tells the server what to do once the user is disconnected, in advance.

Now, I am using AS3. How should I tell the server the same thing as achieved by the 'onDisconnect' method?

When I tried debugging the code in JavaScript, it doesn't seem to send something to the server.(or maybe i am wrong).

Sample code in JavaScript:

```
userRef.on('value', function(snapshot) {
  if (snapshot.val()) {
    userRef.onDisconnect().remove(); //this line does the magic
  }
});
```

What is being done by the `onDisconnect` method which tells the server what to do? What is the equivalent code if written in AS3?

**EDITED:**
The code in AS3, as reference by [here](https://github.com/PhantomAppDevelopment/firebase-as3/tree/master/database), it works for Realtime Database.

```
private var myStream:URLStream;

private function loadLiveFeed():void
{
    var header:URLRequestHeader = new URLRequestHeader("Accept", "text/event-stream");

    var request:URLRequest = new URLRequest("https://<YOUR-PROJECT-ID>.firebaseio.com/breakingnews.json");
    request.requestHeaders.push(header);

    myStream:URLStream = new URLStream();
    myStream.addEventListener(ProgressEvent.PROGRESS, progress);
    myStream.load(request);
}

private function progress(event:ProgressEvent):void
{               
   var message:String = myStream.readUTFBytes(myStream.bytesAvailable);
   trace(message);
}
```

Comment: Well, how do you establish the connection in As3? How does your code look like so far? It doesn't look like they provide an API for As3.

Comment: @null my bad. I just added the code in AS3

Comment: @null you are right. They are not providing the API for AS3. But i am curious how does that 'onDisconnect' method work. Does it (the magic line) send something to server? I feel i am in the dark.

Answer (score 3):

The code you shared accesses the Firebase Database through its [REST API](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/rest/start):

```
new URLRequest("https://<YOUR-PROJECT-ID>.firebaseio.com/breakingnews.json");
```

This means that it is using a connectionless method to interact with the database. Unfortunately that also means that there is no way to register an `onDisconnect()` handler, since it would essentially have to fire between any two HTTP calls that you make.

Comment: can you please elaborate a little bit more? When the javascript 'register' the onDisconnect, does it send something over the network?

Comment: When you register an `onDisconnect()` handler, the actual data that will be written upon disconnect ie pre-calculated and sent to the server. Then when the server detects that the client is gone, it writes the data you specified. But since the REST API is connectionless, there is no clear moment to detect that the client is gone.

Comment: I think i get what you mean now. In that case, is that no way out for this in AS3? Can we use some sort of socket instead of URLRequest?

Comment: There is no native Firebase SDK for ActionScript. I'm not sure if ActionScript can use regular JavaScript libraries, such as the Firebase SDK for JavaScript. But I doubt that anyone would have taken the trouble to wrap the REST API in ActionScript unless they had to.

Comment: Is quite sad if your words are true. Anyway, give me some time before marking the answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

No time to answer this, but you'd have to reverse engineer the communication. Under the hood, it's all just HTTP (or similar) as can be seen in the As3 code. To know what's going on exactly, get a working example code in JavaScript that contains the magic line you are curious about, then execute it in the browser. All requests can be monitored in the developer tools of the browser. You should be able to identify what's being sent.

Also, it's JavaScript, which means you have to have the source code which you can simply read. It might be minified and/or obfuscated, but maybe you can find a readable one.

With the knowledge of what the bare requests look like, you can then implement an API of your own in any language that's capable of performing the necessary network communication.

Comment: lol. Actually i did that (debugging the code through the browser), but i didnt see anything through the network tab (which usually would show if something if sent over the network). And yes, i just found the un-minified version. Anyway, probably i overlook something. I will continue to look into this.

Comment: do you want to mention anything before i close this post. I have no clue what is being captured by wireshark, as posted in https://github.com/PhantomAppDevelopment/firebase-as3/issues/4

I wish someone could say that i am wrong